# What is the make of the most expensive car? CSV, pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to find the make of the car that is the most expensive. I found the highest price using `max(df['price'])` but now I don't know how to use that price to find the make that correlates to it.
Sample:

```
            make    price
0    alfa-romero  13495.0
1    alfa-romero  16500.0
2    alfa-romero  16500.0
3           audi  13950.0
4           audi  17450.0

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

url = 'imports-85-wheader.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

highestprice = max(df['price'])
```

Comment: I couldn't download the file. Perhaps you could post part of the file as table for the ease of visualization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a boolean mask based on that `highest_price` value:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/imports-85.csv'
>>> df = pd.read_csv(csv_url)
>>> df
     symboling  normalized-losses         make fuel-type  ... peak-rpm city-mpg highway-mpg    price
0            3                NaN  alfa-romero       gas  ...   5000.0       21          27  13495.0
1            3                NaN  alfa-romero       gas  ...   5000.0       21          27  16500.0
2            1                NaN  alfa-romero       gas  ...   5000.0       19          26  16500.0
3            2              164.0         audi       gas  ...   5500.0       24          30  13950.0
4            2              164.0         audi       gas  ...   5500.0       18          22  17450.0
..         ...                ...          ...       ...  ...      ...      ...         ...      ...
200         -1               95.0        volvo       gas  ...   5400.0       23          28  16845.0
201         -1               95.0        volvo       gas  ...   5300.0       19          25  19045.0
202         -1               95.0        volvo       gas  ...   5500.0       18          23  21485.0
203         -1               95.0        volvo    diesel  ...   4800.0       26          27  22470.0
204         -1               95.0        volvo       gas  ...   5400.0       19          25  22625.0

[205 rows x 26 columns]
>>> highest_price = max(df['price'])
>>> highest_price
45400.0
>>> make_of_most_expensive_car = df[df['price'] == highest_price]['make'].to_string(index=False).strip()
>>> make_of_most_expensive_car
'mercedes-benz'
```

You can also use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['price'].idxmax(),'make']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# get the highest price from your data without any conditions

max_price = df['price'].max()

# return all of the 'make' values with the highest value of the price (using numpy.unique)
# NOTE: there can be more than only one result if your dataset would be larger

np.unique(df[df['price'] == max_price]['make'])
```